# How to implement a progress bar on top of UIWebView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiprogressview

I am developing application for iOS7 in xcode 5. I have a view controller `ADMSViewController`
The .h file is as follows

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "IMTWebView.h"
@interface ADMSViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate,IMTWebViewProgressDelegate>
{
    NSString *barcode;
    NSString *vinNumber;
    NSTimer *timer;

}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
@end
```

The .m file is as follows

```
#import "ADMSViewController.h"

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@implementation ADMSViewController

@synthesize webView;
@synthesize progressView;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com/"]]];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];

}

- (void)webView:(IMTWebView *)_webView didReceiveResourceNumber:(int)resourceNumber totalResources:(int)totalResources {
    [self.progressView setProgress:((float)resourceNumber) / ((float)totalResources)];
    if (resourceNumber == totalResources) {
        _webView.resourceCount = 0;
        _webView.resourceCompletedCount = 0;
    }
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.webView = nil;
    self.progressView = nil;
}

@end
```

The IMTWebview.h file is as follows

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class IMTWebView;

@protocol IMTWebViewProgressDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) webView:(IMTWebView*)webView didReceiveResourceNumber:(int)resourceNumber totalResources:(int)totalResources;
@end

@interface IMTWebView : UIWebView {
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int resourceCount;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int resourceCompletedCount;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<IMTWebViewProgressDelegate> progressDelegate;

@end
```

the IMTWebCiew.m file is as follows

```
#import "IMTWebView.h"

@interface UIWebView ()
-(id)webView:(id)view identifierForInitialRequest:(id)initialRequest fromDataSource:(id)dataSource;
-(void)webView:(id)view resource:(id)resource didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:(id)dataSource;
-(void)webView:(id)view resource:(id)resource didFailLoadingWithError:(id)error fromDataSource:(id)dataSource;
@end

@implementation IMTWebView

@synthesize progressDelegate;
@synthesize resourceCount;
@synthesize resourceCompletedCount;

-(id)webView:(id)view identifierForInitialRequest:(id)initialRequest fromDataSource:(id)dataSource
{
    [super webView:view identifierForInitialRequest:initialRequest fromDataSource:dataSource];
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:resourceCount++];
}

- (void)webView:(id)view resource:(id)resource didFailLoadingWithError:(id)error fromDataSource:(id)dataSource {
    [super webView:view resource:resource didFailLoadingWithError:error fromDataSource:dataSource];
    resourceCompletedCount++;
    if ([self.progressDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webView:didReceiveResourceNumber:totalResources:)]) {
        [self.progressDelegate webView:self didReceiveResourceNumber:resourceCompletedCount totalResources:resourceCount];
    }
}

-(void)webView:(id)view resource:(id)resource didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:(id)dataSource
{
    [super webView:view resource:resource didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:dataSource];
    resourceCompletedCount++;
    if ([self.progressDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webView:didReceiveResourceNumber:totalResources:)]) {
        [self.progressDelegate webView:self didReceiveResourceNumber:resourceCompletedCount totalResources:resourceCount];
    }
}

@end
```

My issue is that the progress bar is not animating in the webview. Please help me as I am a newbie to ios development. If there is any other method to implement the same, do inform me.
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Did you use logging or breakpoints to make sure that `resource:didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:` is being called as you expect?

Comment: no its not being called.

Comment: link your sample project

Comment: what do you mean by link your sample project?

Comment: So the issue is NOT that the progress bar is not animating. The issue has to do with this IMTWebView thing.

Comment: so what has to be done?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of thing, you can only really 'detect' page size by using Content-Length headers, but otherwise you can still present a loading control (like one of the moving zebra crossing type bars which doesn't show a discrete % progress but shows that activity is occurring.. or even just a UIActivityIndicator). You could try a ready-made class like http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest too, which CAN show progress. The author states:

ASIWebPageRequests do not currently support progress tracking for an entire request with its external resources. However, progress updates from external resource requests are passed on to your delegate, so with a bit of work it may be possible to implement this yourself.